# How to imitate arrays using less guards?

Tags: less

Is it possible to do something like this?
Or maybe is there a simpler and adequate «sugar» solution?

```
.bd (@border:0, @style:[solid,double,dotted]){
    border: @border * 1px @style;
}

.dummy-style{
   .bd(1, @[3]); //border: 1px dotted;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to imitate arrays because arrays do already exist in Less (they just do not have `[]` operator since it's already has another semantics in CSS).

```
.bd(@border, @style) {
    border: @border * 1px extract(solid double dotted, @style);
}

.dummy-style {
   .bd(1, 3);
}
```

(I'm not counting that:)

> It's not a "sugar" in any way. Many people would consider this as antihuman cryptographic obfuscation: when anyone but you sees `.bd(1, 3)` how can she know what the heck this is supposed to mean at all? But of course it's completely up to you to decide if you're fine with "write-only" code.